# error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 31: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm Trying to decode bytes to utf-8
this is my script

```
import subprocess

meta_data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles'])
print(type(meta_data.decode("utf-8")))
```

Can Someone help me to fix that?

error:
error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 31: invalid start byte

Comment: this is the error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 31: invalid start byte

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: We can't know which encoding your Windows is set up to emit; probably check with `chcp`